# How can I make a button change it's shape with every click (music button)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to design a music button for a game like [geochallenge](http://apps.facebook.com/geochallenge/?pf_ref=sb&ref=ts)

Comment: I think you should ask questions after at least trying something. If not code, then at least your approach on the problem.

Comment: U are right , i will try to that , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to see the geochallenge game , for some reason i get an empty facebook page ,  but for a button to change its shape you can create a function that will call the graphics property

```
var color:uint = 0x990000;

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    buttonGraphics(event.target as MovieClip)
}

function buttonGraphics(mc:MovieClip ):void
{
    mc.graphics.clear; // clear the previous shape
    mc.graphics.beginFill(color );
    etc... //make the changes you need
}
```